# Как получить индекс максимального элемента в векторе с умными указателями? C++

Tags: c++, vector, c++17, unique-ptr

У меня есть вектор std::vectorstd::unique_ptr<IShape> и у IShape есть метод GetArea(), который возвращает площадь. Так вот есть ли в C++ какой-то алгоритм который позволит индекс элемента с максимальной площадью? Я пробовал через std::max_element с компроматором, но он конечно же не работает, тк как я понимаю уникальный указатель он на то и уникальный не может передаваться в функцию.
[image: код описанный выше]

Comment: а как Ваш компилятор компилирует картинку? код - это текст!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поменять тип параметров компаратора на `const std::unique_ptr<IShape> &`.